# Populate table using submited form (javascript)

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I am trying to learn javascript but so far i came to a complete stop. I've made a html webpage with a form on it (3 fields : Name ,Surname, Gender) and table below . i'm trying to list the data the user is typing in that form  and display it below in the table using javascript (appendChild)

How could i do this easily? Examples are highly appreciated.

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Test1</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

    <script language="javascript">


function addRow(){
...


    </script>

  </HEAD>
  <BODY>


<form>
Name:<br>
<input type="text" id="name"><br>
Last Name: <br> 
<input type="text" id="lname"><br>
Gender: <br>
<input type="text" id ="gender"> <br>
<input type="submit" id ="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addRow()">
</form> 


<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test, test</td>
<td>test, test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test2, test1</td>
<td>test2, test1</td>
</tr>
</table>


  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: post the current code you've tried so that you can be guided in the right path. :-)

Comment: i've already searched online but all i could find is predefined text and not the one received through a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Give your table an identifier:

```
<table border="1" id="results">
```

**Step 2:**

Get a DOM reference to this table:

```
var table = document.getElementById('results');
```

**Step3:**

Make the elements you will insert:

```
var row = document.createElement('tr');
var td1 = document.createElement('td');
var td2 = document.createElement('td');
var td3 = document.createElement('td');
```

**Step4:**

Set their values:

```
td1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value;
td2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('lname').value;
td3.innerHTML = document.getElementById('gender').value;
row.appendChild(td1);
row.appendChild(td2);
row.appendChild(td3);
```

**Step5:**

Insert into DOM:

```
table.children[0].appendChild(row);
```

Combined, we have:

```
function addRow(){
    var table = document.getElementById('results');
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    var td3 = document.createElement('td');
    td1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value;
    td2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    td3.innerHTML = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    table.children[0].appendChild(row);
}
```

If you want to prepend a row, you can use something like this:

```
table.children[0].insertBefore(row,table.children[0].childNodes[1]);
```

instead of using `appendChild` to append the row. The rest is the same. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xnWSV/6/) example.

Comment: works to a certain degree but hides the values right after submiting the form

Comment: @user1771162 seems to be working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xnWSV/5/)

Comment: well i had to add a "return false" statement otherwise the form would just reset. now i'm running into another problem as i'm trying to add a "addbefore" function but again it's not working. how could i do it the easy way?

Comment: @user1771162 I've added the information you requested.

Comment: thanks Asad. what if i want to insert an addAfter function? should i just replace the previos addBefore data?

Comment: @user1771162 The original code by default adds the row at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xnWSV/)

JavaScript:

```
(function setup() {
    "use strict";

    var fNameElem = document.getElementById("fName");
    var lNameElem = document.getElementById("lName");
    var genderElem = document.getElementById("gender");
    var ageElem = document.getElementById("age");
    var tableElem = document.getElementById("table");
    document.getElementById("display").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var newRow = tableElem.insertRow(-1);
        var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
        var newText = document.createTextNode(lNameElem.value + ", " + fNameElem.value);
        newCell.appendChild(newText);
        newCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
        newText  = document.createTextNode(genderElem.value);
        newCell.appendChild(newText);
        newCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
        newText  = document.createTextNode(ageElem.value);
        newCell.appendChild(newText);
        fNameElem.value = "";
        lNameElem.value = "";
        ageElem.value = "";
        tableElem.value = "";
    });
})();​
```

HTML:

```
First Name:<br>
<input type="text" id="fName" /><br>
Last Name: <br> 
<input type="text" id="lName" /><br>
Gender: <br>
<input type="text" id="gender" /><br>
Age: <br>
<input type="text" id ="age" /> <br>
<input type="button" id ="display" value="Display" /><br>
<table id= "table" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
</table>
```